# How to prevent the code execution if a textbox is empty?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to prevent the code execution if user leave a textbox empty

```
If tx01.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
If tx01.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub  //  also tried
```

But user can simply write a space (or any number of spaces) and - prevention doesn't work.
I need characters in this box (numeric and nonNumeric), but not only spaces.
How can I do this, pls ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like

```
if trim(tx01.Value) = "" then Exit sub
```

Trim removes leading and trailing whitespace characters.

Comment: Yes, that's it. ThankYoy - Tony and Ratan.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a `Trim()` in the textbox value check.